# svg element layer / overlap / overlay / superimposition

Tags: svg, overlay, d3.js, layer, overlap

With a view to making them hot pluggable / draggable / scaleable, I've been playing around with Mike Bostock's d3 [three little circles](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html) examples.

While doing this, I stumbled across an issue (using Firefox 16.0.2, btw - normally fine for svg) which, though in itself not serious, somehow bugs me: namely that though always present in the resulting HTML, any attempt at **overlaying** the rectangular viewing area with the **button** element fails.

I've tried following each piece of advice at the foot of [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/252) exchange, but these have had no impact.

Here my base code, whereby the button is shown **outside** the circle's containing svg view area. The groupings are part of preparations for experiments with drag n drop / scalability:

```
var root = d3.selectAll("g#tool-2");

var g0 = root
.append("g")
.attr("class", "g0")
.attr("id", function (d, i) { return d.tool});

var g01 = g0
.append("g")
.attr("class", "g01")
.attr("id", function (d, i) { return d.tool});

var g02 = g0
.insert("g")
.attr("class", "g02")
.attr("id", function (d, i) { return d.tool});

var svg = g01
.insert("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var button = g02
.append("div")
.attr("class", "button")
.attr("id", function (d, i) { return d.tool}) 
.append("button")
.text(function(d) { return "Run" });

svg.selectAll(".little")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "little")
.attr("cx", x)
.attr("cy", y)
.attr("r", 12);

console.log("Got past circle creation");

button
.on("click", function() {

    svg.selectAll(".select").remove();

    svg.selectAll(".select")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "select")
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .attr("r", 60)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
    .style("stroke-width", 3)
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("r", 12)
    .style("stroke-opacity", 1);
});
```

Appended to **any** of root, g0, g01 or g02, the button is shown outside the rectangular container. All well and good. Here, for example, the html resulting from the code shown above:

```
<g id="tool-2" class="g0">
    <g id="tool-2" class="g01">
        <svg height="180" width="360">
            <circle r="12" cy="45" cx="180" class="little"></circle>
            <circle r="12" cy="90" cx="60" class="little"></circle>
            <circle r="12" cy="135" cx="300" class="little"></circle>
            <circle style="fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3;" r="12" cy="45" cx="180" class="select"></circle>
            <circle style="fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3;" r="12" cy="90" cx="60" class="select"></circle>
            <circle style="fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3;" r="12" cy="135" cx="300" class="select"></circle>
        </svg>
    </g>
    <g id="tool-2" class="g02">
        <div id="tool-2" class="button">
            <button>Run</button>
        </div>
    </g>
</g>
```

Regardless of append element used, however, whether using

- z-index
- x & y coordinates
- dx & dy coordinates
- with or without id
- with or without class
- with or without positioning

..the button, though **present in the resulting html**, either continues to be shown outside the container, or is simply not displayed.

There seems to be an issue with svg overlaying with which I'm really not familiar. Any hints?

Thanks
Thug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see you're mixing HTML elements into SVG. That's not valid. You can wrap the HTML elements in a [`<foreignObject>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement) and see if you're more lucky with that.

You have to make sure that the proper namespace for the foreign content is added. Here is a complete working example ([try on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mzak8/)):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <g class="g0">
        <g class="g01">
            <svg height="180" width="360">
                <circle r="12" cy="45" cx="180" class="little"></circle>
                <circle r="12" cy="90" cx="60" class="little"></circle>
                <circle r="12" cy="135" cx="300" class="little"></circle>
                <circle style="fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3;" r="12" cy="45" cx="180" class="select"></circle>
                <circle style="fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3;" r="12" cy="90" cx="60" class="select"></circle>
                <circle style="fill: none; stroke: red; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 3;" r="12" cy="135" cx="300" class="select"></circle>
            </svg>
        </g>
        <g class="g02">
            <foreignObject width="100" height="50">
                <div class="button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <button>Run</button>
                </div>
            </foreignObject>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your suggestion. foreignObject was in fact one of a variety of container elements I tried out (g, div, foreignObject, svg). I've given it a fresh try, but get the same odd behaviour. Given the breadth of attempts, I begin to suspect the problem goes beyond the issue of simple layering or structure. :-(

Comment: Thanks very much, Thomas, I really don't know if I'd have found my way to this information. Above all, I see that it works. :-)

Decisive to the correct placement of the button is the replacement of svg with foreignObject (and requiredExtensions attribute).

On the other hand, the xmls attribute, whether added to the top-level svg element, or the lowest-level (button) div seems to have no impact.

Now all I have to do is to figure out why this didn't work in my own code... :-)

Comment: It helps to have an understanding of XML namespaces. Of course, all HTML elements have to be in the HTML namespace, and all SVG elements have to be in the SVG namespace. This means, if you put the `foreignObject` element in the HTML namespace by giving it `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, it won't be recognized as SVG's `foreignObject` element. Instead, it appears to be a non-standard HTML element because it's in the HTML namespace. Likewise, if you don't put `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` on the `div` element, it appears to be a non-standard HTML element.

Comment: Just re-read my comment there: Of course the final bit has to read: Likewise, if you don't put `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` on the `div` element, it appears to be a non-standard *SVG* element (because it's still in the SVG namespace, like its surrounding).

Comment: As my html is generated by d3.js (which comes with common namespaces predefined), explicit mention of all but the requiredExtensions attribute seem to be unnecessary. This has been outlined by Mike Bostock: (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/d3-js/4pOdrFpgjTo).

Comment: This works on Firefox but not Chrome or Safari... any idea how I can get it working?

Comment: @FrancesKR: I removed the requiredExtension attribute, and now it seems to work!  Can you confirm that?

Comment: Now it works on Chrome and Firefox, but not IE 10... I don't have access to test on Safari right now.  I'm not sure if the previous version worked on IE 10, I can't quite remember what the requiredExtension attribute was.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you'll be able to get IE to work at all. I don't know how one should read [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which says "The foreignObject element is not supported."  [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=foreignobject) claims IE supports foreignObject partially.